# Codeigniter merge arrays to a single array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out this thing in codeigniter, but because I am a beginner, I am having some trouble finding the solution for it.

I have a table named `tasks` and another table named `progress`. So a number of tasks are inserted in `tasks` table and progress for those tasks are inserted in `progress` table. I am using different table to track progress because I may need to track down the progress history for each tasks later on.

```
$all_tasks = $this->task_m->get_by(array('user_id'=> $this->session->userdata('id')));

foreach ($all_tasks as $task) {
    $progress = $this->progress_m->get_by(array('task_id'=> $task->id));

};
```

So what I am trying to do is add the entries of both the `$task` and `$progress` to an array so that I can loop through it and display the combined result for a task at a time.

There are two entries in `tasks` table and the value of `$tasks` is :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(28) "Sample task to do sometihing"
    ["description"]=>
    string(28) "Sample task to do sometihing"
    ["priority"]=>
    string(4) "high"
    ["status"]=>
    string(7) "pending"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-27 23:26:09"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-27 23:26:09"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Sample task 2"
    ["description"]=>
    string(11) "Sample desc"
    ["priority"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["status"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-28 00:20:17"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-28 00:20:17"
  }
}
```

There are two entries in `progress` table and the value for each `$progress` is :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["task_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["percentage"]=>
    string(2) "68"
    ["description"]=>
    string(17) "About to complete"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-18 00:00:00"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-12 00:00:00"
  }
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#27 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["task_id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["percentage"]=>
    string(2) "56"
    ["description"]=>
    string(6) "Sample"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-05 00:00:00"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-14 00:00:00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
$all_tasks = $this->task_m->get_by(array('user_id'=> $this->session->userdata('id')));

foreach ($all_tasks as $task) {
    $task->progress_list = $this->progress_m->get_by(array('task_id'=> $task->id));
};
```

Comment: This helped. Added the progress object to `$task->progress_list` and now I can access the progress values as `$task->progress_list->percentage` . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use ActiveRecord to join the two tables, run the query and then you have one result object with all the info?  I am assuming they share a common key correct?  If not, you may want to re-think the way your DB is laid out.  If you don't want to use ActiveRecord you could write the query in standard MySQL and use the query() method.